# async await and shared objects

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I'm using the async / await pattern to perform some CPU heavy operations on an object (my method is awaitable), which works as supposed without blocking the UI thread.

However, when i pass the object as a parameter to the ctor of a new window (the new window is a logging window that needs access to the processed object), my UI thread blocks (which I kinda understand why).

to get around this I could wrap the execution of the calculation in a

```
Task.Run(async () => { await _myObject.PerformCalculations(); });
```

and then simply call

```
var logWindow = new LogWindow(_myObject);
logWindow.Show();
```

This works (of course) but i have a lot of dispatcher calls when the object raises events, which I wouldn't have to deal with if I could do without the Task.Run call.

So, my question is, can I somehow do without the Task.Run call and still pass the object to the logging window without blocking my UI thread?

**EDIT**

I'm sorry for the stripped down example, I actually intended to make the question as simple as possible to understand and failed miserably.

In a more general way: I have an object that raises events on certain conditions. When an event is raised, I want to perform updates on the UI. An event always fires from the thread that was created using Task.Run(...). Hence, dispatcher calls to the UI thread. So, I want to perform the calculations using async / await (already works) and pass the object to my logging window (blocks).

When I use Task.Run, everything works of course, but wherever I subscribe to an event of the object from the UI thread I have to use dispatcher calls to the UI thread, because the event fires from the thread that Task.Run created. These dispatcher calls I would like to avoid. **In fact, if I wouldn't pass the object to the logging window, and call the Show() method, the UI thread wouldn't block and everything would work as supposed. No dispatcher calls needed in the event handlers.**

Comment: There's no need to use an asynchronous delegate when you're already calling `Task.Run`. Just use `Task.Run(_myObject.PerformCalculations)`

Comment: wow. Jon Skeet himself. :) thanks!
however, it's not as simple as my example might suggest. I have to use the delegate because I have more than one command, and in fact I wrap the commands in a try/catch block inside the delegate.

Comment: the logWindow.Show(); somehow got lost when pasting the code.

Comment: But even so, do you actually need it to be an async delegate? Your question really isn't clear, to be honest.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. You mention dispatcher calls when the object raises events. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Can't you designate the event handlers with the async keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of hard to get a clear picture of your situation. But it looks to me like you could do with some refactoring.

Consider `PerformCalculations`: this is a method returning `Task` (thus advertising itself as `async`-friendly) that does heavy CPU usage (thus not actually *being* `async`-friendly). The first thing I would look at is dividing up the logic in `PerformCalculations` so that the CPU-bound portions use their own `Task.Run`, leaving `PerformCalcuations` as an `async` method that doesn't (directly) hit the CPU:

```
public async Task PerformCalculationsAsync()
{
  while (...)
  {
    await Task.Run(<next calculations>);
    RaiseEvent();
  }
}
```

The point of this refactoring is to divide the CPU code in `Task.Run` from the UI-ish code raising events. Also consider using the standard `IProgress<T>` approach if your events are logically progress updates or if this kind of refactoring would be too difficult for your code; `IProgress<T>.Report` can be called from any thread.

You may also find my posts on [`async` constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) and [`async` properties](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html) (particularly the data-binding section) to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
// awaitable as well - await this in another async void/Task method (e.g. commanding)
public async Task MyAsyncProcess()
{
    await _myObject.PerformCalculations();
    var logWindow = new LogWindow(_myObject);
}
```

`Task.Run()` executes an asynchronous method synchronously, so in this case you pretty much lack of use of the async/await pattern. Make the method where you execute your code `async` as well and await it somewhere else. Or alternatively use some `FireAndForget` logic.

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to my question? It's not the PerformCalculations() call that blocks, but creating a new window and passing in a reference to that object.

Comment: hm. now the LogWindow doesn't show at all when I call logWindow.Show();

Comment: This works for me with `Caliburn.Micro`, how is commanding implemented in your code?

Comment: I don't perform any user input on the object at all. If it's that what you mean by commanding.

Comment: Okay, so forget about commanding. Do you call this method in a synchronous context like the `App` ctor?

Comment: I call that method in the (async!) click event handler of a button.

Comment: WPF. Should have mentioned that, sorry.